# Retrofit - Android - Handling multiple type keys and values with gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

So I've been having some trouble with an api that I want to consume from my application when dealing with multiple types from the keys and values of the response json.

Let me show you the json response:

```
{
   "error":[

   ],
   "result":{
      "field1":[
         [
            1544258160,
            "57.15",
            "57.15",
            "57.15",
            "57.15",
            "0.00",
            "0.00000000",
            0
         ],
         [
            1544258220,
            "56.89",
            "56.89",
            "56.89",
            "56.89",
            "56.89",
            "2.94406281",
            1
         ]
      ],
      "field2":1544301240
   }
}
```

and here is the representation of the pojo class:

```
data class Response(val error: List<String>, val result: LinkedTreeMap<String, List<List<Result>>>)

data class Result(
    val time: Double,
    val open: String,
    val high: String,
    val low: String,
    val close: String,
    val vwap: String,
    val volume: String,
    val count: Double
)
```

I know that the current structure fails to represent the json format. but I have run out of ideas.

btw the stack error is saying this:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER
```

edit: adding a bit more context

I'm using Gsonconverter for the retrofit builder.

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_URL).client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been a while but still i already came to a conclusion of what i need.

```
data class OHLCResponse(
private val error: List<String>,
val result: LinkedTreeMap<String, Any>)
```

turns out that on the LinkedTreeMap class i just needed to pass the second class type parameter as `Any` and it can be down casted to anything that you need.

also i leave here a nice tool that can help you map your json responses into kotlin plain objects/DTOs:

https://app.quicktype.io/

thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
"field2":1544301240
```

You defined like below:

```
val result: LinkedTreeMap<String, List<List<Result>>>
```

but instead of that you get number!!!

**EDIT**

Just try this:

```
data class Response(val error: List<String>, val result: YourModel)

data class YourModel(val field1: LinkedTreeMap<String, List<List<Result>>>, val field2: Double)

data class Result(
    val time: Double,
    val open: String,
    val high: String,
    val low: String,
    val close: String,
    val vwap: String,
    val volume: String,
    val count: Double
)
```

Comment: yup you are right, but hw can i handle that scenario where value types are different from one set to another?

Comment: could you send your full state json that you may recieve?

Comment: full json is too large but API is public, here is an example: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XZECZUSD

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Gson `JsonDeserializer` for the filed1, filed2 types. 
It is more manually written code, but this way you can check the type of the filed and call the right deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,what make the error is your response field(result),it's different type.however.you just use the first type `Response(val error: List<String>, val result:LinkedTreeMap<String, List<List<Result>>>` receive all the json.

in my view,you can use below ways to solve it.

First，redefine you receive model,maybe you can use the Gson JsonObject and when deal with value remember check the type.

Second,discuss with your background server engineer,agree on the every type response.may be the "field2" can be "field2:[[]]"

Next,change your model.may be you define below it

```
@Serialized("field1")
LinkedTreeMap<String, List<List<Result>>> field;
@Serialized("field2")
String fields;
```

hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with such a solution in adapter class .

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = leagueTableList[0].size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LeagueTableViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val gs = Gson()
    val js = gs.toJson(leagueTableList[0][position])
    val standing = gs.fromJson(js, Standing::class.java)
    holder.view.table = standing
    holder.bind(standing,onItemClick)
}
```